# Which airline will get me from Paris or London, to Japan, and has a zero fatality rate?

Tags: safety, accidents, accident-statistics

I only fly with airlines with a zero fatality rate (it helps my fear of flying, yes it might not be logical, I know:)… but have so far only travelled around Europe and to Africa with Easyjet and Ryan Air.

Now I want to go to Japan (from either Paris or London).

Is there an option for me?

Comment: The chance of you being the first is still non zero though.

Comment: I have proposed an edit based on the fact that OP accepted an answer talking about airlines, not airliners.

Comment: That said, wouldn't this be a much better fit on [travel.se]?

Comment: Please remember the [be nice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy, and assume good intention. The comment of yours ive deleted was not very nice considering someone was trying to point you to a (potentially) better place to answer your question.

Comment: Note that the fatality rate for 2017 for **all airlines worldwide** was zero.

Comment: @ymb1. Given the question has 3 tags that are relevant it would appear to be very much **on topic**?  It's a question about aviation safety, of which there are 650 in aviation stack exchange. And it's been given a good answer.

Comment: @Cloud *"people like to close questions for fun"* Look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [help]. One of the bullet points about questions that are *off topic* is specifically *"passenger aspects" of commercial air travel*. It doesn't really make more sense to ask a pilot, aircraft mechanic or air traffic controller about on which airline to book a ticket, than it does to ask a travel agent about the finer points of aircraft jet engine design or the aerodynamic properties of an autogyro. They might know, but it's not their job.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Given the question has 3 tags that are relevant it would appear to be very much on topic? It's a question about aviation safety, of which there are 650 in aviation stack exchange. And it's been given a good answer

Comment: @Cloud - If 3+ of our highest rep users think its off-topic then guess what... it's off topic. Just copying a misguided comment from someone else doesnt change that. Not *all* aviation safety questions are on-topic, this being one of them.

Comment: @Jamiec.  I agree, not all aviation safety questions may be on-topic.  If he'd just asked for the cheapest ticket, it would be a question just about the "passenger" aspect of travel. But he asked about the safest. Safety is a technical aspect. The list of topics given in the help centre isn't very broad at all. For example, jet engines aren't mentioned at all, yet there are 450 questions about them. So, if a question **can** link to 3 tags that **are** relevant, it does beg the question how it's off topic? Or are you saying the tags are not relevant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qantas to Singapore, onwards to Japan with Jetstar, also owned by Qantas.

From [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Qantas_fatal_accidents):

> In 2014, Qantas was rated the world's safest airline by Airline Ratings.

Rainman already knew..

For jet transport, Qantas is a zero-fatality-rate airline, has been for over 50 years, flying some of the longest distance air services in the world. The flying boats during wartime are a long time behind us.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm guessing there is no direct route?

Comment: @Cloud unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is KLM, they've not had an accident since 1981 and that one was due to a freak weather phenomenon that nobody could have foreseen snapping off the wing of a brand new aircraft like it was made of tissue paper (technically it wasn't even KLM, it was a regional subsidiary, the last mainline accident they had was Tenerife in 1977 over 40 years ago).

They'd probably get you there faster than Qantas too, as you'd be changing planes in Amsterdam rather than having to take a major detour to Australia.

Comment: Thanks for this, do you have links to the pages of those accidents, sounds interesting.

Comment: @Cloud I suspect that'd be KLM Flight 4805 in 1977. You can start at the [Wikipedia page on the Tenerife airport disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster), then follow its citations.

Comment: Qantas flies London- Singapore.

Comment: @Cloud that's the one. Before that the last fatalities in KLM flights I know about were on a Constellation that crashed on takeoff from Shannon somewhere in the 1950s. The 1981 crash was an NLM Cityhopper (now KLM Cityhopper but an independent airline owned by KLM at the time) Fokker 28 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLM_CityHopper_Flight_431

Comment: Saying that KLM has had no accidents since 1981 might make the asker more comfortable with KLM, but that comfort is probably completely undone by then immediately describing the 1981 accident in graphic detail. "New Aircraft Wings Like Tissue Paper" is the headline I'm left with.

Comment: @ToddWilcox well, the weather conditions were such that no aircraft would have survived them... And it was a fully owned subsidiary, not the main company